# Mapping data from JSON not parsing well

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I have a chart.js program with the data formatted this way:

```js
"fieldData" : {
  "CategoryLFStat1" : "ACTE",
  "Category_LF_Stat2" : "DIAGNOSTIC",
  "Category_LF_Stat3" : "LABORATOIRE"
}
```

My JavaScript functions

```js
var list = data.filter(function (e) {
  return e.fieldData.categorie === prod
});
```

or

```js
var allProducts = data.map(function (e) {
  return e.fieldData.categorie
});
```

Are working fine.

But when my JSON data don't have the `fieldData` tag like this:

```js
{
  "categorie" : "ACTE",
  "date" : "4/01/2021",
  "price" : 56.25
}, {
  "categorie" : "ACTE",
  "date" : "4/01/2021",
  "price" : 31
},
```

Then I don't know how to parse this data in the same JavaScript functions.

I've tried :

```js
var allProducts = data.map(function (e) {
  return e.categorie
});
```

But it's not working.

Comment: I have updated your question *Note with the \* you can not format your text as code*

Comment: "it's not working" isn't much of a problem statement. Are there errors? Does nothing happen? Does something happen that you don't expect? See [ask] for more tips.

Comment: @Alex "not" or "now"? Also, you can already use three contiguous back-ticks before/after the code block to format.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl "Note" the OP has formatted his code with \* var x \*

Comment: Can I see what is stored in allProducts? I suspect you're not actually winding up with an array of objects with a categorie property. Maybe you're just getting one object and `map` doesn't exist on it.

Comment: Your question makes very little sense. I'm guessing there's a missing property somewhere that you are expecting, but it's very hard to figure out what you're trying to do from your description. Please try clarifying what you're asking, use more examples if you must.

Comment: not wroking means chart is not displaying in the second example adn displaying in the first.
It's like I can not access to the JSON key value if there is not the filedData before each array of JSON value.
Or how to access to them with the same javascript code but without the fieldData in front of all tje JSON array

Comment: sorry that's the complete javascript code :

Answer (score 0):

sorry that's the complete javascript function :

```
    var data = **Data** ;
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    console.log(value, index, self);
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
var year;
var dates = data.map(function (e) {
    var date = new Date(e.data.date);
    year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.toLocaleString('default', {
        month: 'long'
    })
    return moment(date).format("MMM");
});
var allProducts = data.map(function (e) {
    return e.data.categorie
});
var products = allProducts.filter(onlyUnique);
var array = [];
products.forEach(function (e, i) {
    var prod = e;
    var list = data.filter(function (e) {
        return e.data.categorie === prod
    })
    console.log(list);
    var s = list.map(function (e) {
        return e.data.price
    });
    var obj = {
        name: e,
        data: s
    };
    array[i] = obj
    return array
})
console.log(array);
var categories = dates.filter(onlyUnique);
var series = array;
var options = {
    series: series,
    chart: {
        type: "bar",
        height: 500,
        stacked: true,
        events: {
            click: function (event, chartContext, config) {
window.FileMaker.PerformScript("Event","Hi");
                console.dir(chartContext);
                console.dir(config)
            }
        }
    },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    style: {
        colors: ['#333'],
fontSize: '10px'
    },
   
  },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            horizontal: false,
            startingShape: 'flat',
            endingShape: 'flat',
            columnWidth: '90%',
            dataLabels: {
                position: 'bottom',
                orientation: 'horizontal',
                maxItems: 20
            }
        },
    },
    stroke: {
        width: 0
    },
    title: {
        text: "Product Sales for " + year,
    },
    xaxis: {
        categories: categories,
        labels: {
            style: {
                fontSize: '16px'
            }
        }
    },
    yaxis: {
        title: {
            text: undefined,
            labels: {
                formatter: function (val) {
                    return val;
                },
            },
        },
    },
    tooltip: {
        y: {
            formatter: function (val) {
                return val;
            },
        },
    },
    fill: {
        opacity: 1,
    },
    legend: {
        position: "top",
        horizontalAlign: "left",
        offsetX: 40,
    },
};
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

Comment: everywhere there is a e.data.categorie or e.data.date or e.data.price I guess this code is wrong.

Comment: it works well if I put e.fieldData.price or e.fieldDarta.categorie or e.fieldData.date for the charting 
but if the JSON data starts with { filedData
If not then I've tried to put e.data instead of e.fieldData because at the begining of the js the var data is define by the JSON data